# Is there any method to generate unique random numbers always when ever i run the stored procedure in my sql

Tags: mysql

i want to know is there any method to generate unique random numbers always when ever i execute  stored procedure in my SQL
The main factor is that when i execute  My SQL stored procedure for the second time it should generate that numbers which it have not generated in the first  time  and the range of random numbers will be from 1 to 10000000.

Can i do this by with out checking the table for  whether the generated number already exists  in it or not as it slow down the execution process.

Comment: If possible suggest me an alternate optimized solution

Comment: you can have a look at MySQL functions like UUID() and UUID_SHORT()

Comment: Can i specify any range in UUID_SHORT() and one more how to generate 100 random numbers in mysql with out loop